# Mysql dates range, from 2

Tags: mysql, date, select

my english sucks, so I will start with the example:

My database:

```
id -|- name ---|---start . - - -|---end . -- - - |-- description
0 --|-- task --|-- 2015-10-05 --|-- 2015-10-23 --|-- lorem ipsum
1 --|-- task --|-- 2015-09-22 --|-- 2015-09-28 --|-- lorem ipsum
2 --|-- task --|-- 2015-10-11 --|-- 2015-10-14 --|-- lorem ipsum
3 --|-- task --|-- 2015-10-02 --|-- 2015-10-17 --|-- lorem ipsum
```

And i want to select ongoing records only from 2015-10-08 to 2015-10-20.
 In this example i need id's: 0,2,3. How can I do that?
Thank you in advance for your tips

Comment: start and end both between those dates, or overlapping?

Comment: For examples, what about start,ends like: `2015-10-07, 2015-10-21` OR `2015-09-01,2015-10-08` OR `2015-10-20,2015-12-01`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work to find overlapping date ranges; the session variables (@vars) are optional, and just used for clarity.

```
SET @date0 := 20151008;
SET @dateN := 20151020;
SELECT * 
FROM theTable 
WHERE start BETWEEN @date0 AND @dateN
OR end BETWEEN @date0 AND @dateN
OR (start < @date0 AND end > @dateN)
;
```

I feel like this (below) should theoretically work (and be faster), but I could swear I've tried it before and it failed (*but I could have been trying to find something more complicated than just "overlaps"*):

```
SET @date0 := 20151008;
SET @dateN := 20151020;
SELECT * 
FROM theTable 
WHERE end >= @date0 AND start <= @dateN
;
```

*Edit: Oh, I just noticed this one was suggested by Strawberry yesterday.*

Comment: I think you should remove your first answer; I can't see how it's useful. Then again, you're second answer is a little derivative ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry I left the first because for people not well-versed in the finer points of boolean logic, it is clearer than the "simplest" form of `NOT (ending before OR starting after)`

Comment: So it's deliberately patronising? ;-)

Comment: I swear; I get criticized for providing minimal answers with little explanation, and criticized if they aren't. There is no pleasing you people. :-)

Comment: Yeah, it's a tough old world here on SO.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE start >= '2015-10-08'  AND end <= '2015-10-20';